# How do I reset the Survival Trial with the option to sweep them?

Tags: naruto-online

I've been able to Sweep the first couple of the Survival Trial levels, but it seems random. I don't remember if I was able to sweep them because I previously cleared all 12 levels before I reset or not. Is there some sort of trick to being able to sweep the Survival Trials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to finish all 12 check points, I've done so 3 days in a row and for all 3 days swept up to 7th CP. Though we are suppose to be able to seep up to 9th CP. I'll find out tomorrow if 4th try does it.

Comment: Yeah I've gotten up to level 10 for the past week and it seems to be stuck there. Pretty sweet not having to do 1-9 anymore.